# Why does the dataframe becomes a series?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, series

Why does the following function *groupby().size()* change the dataframe into a series? In the first row I get back the results of the *info()* function but in the third I receive an error. *'Series' object has no attribute 'info'*.

```
print(df_injury_record.info())
test = df_injury_record.groupby(["Surface"]).size()
print(test.info())
```

How does the function look like when I want to have it in a dataframe?

Greetings

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It returns a `series`, as just one feature per group (so it doesn't return all your columns). The documentation says it:

> pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.size
>
> Compute group sizes.
>
> Returns: ***Series***, number of rows in each group.

Just add `.to_frame()` at the end if you really want a `dataframe`.

Comment: to add more context the reason it returns a Series is because `size` is the same for all columns, so only a single result is returned.